# ASP.Net Session Not Invalidated After Logout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I have a ASP.Net application in my login page I call

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut 
Session.Abandon() 
Session.Clear()
```

however the Appscan is taking the ASPXAUTH cookie value then after logout is able to re-inject the cookie value to gain access to protected pages.

Microsoft has acknowledged a problem but only offers advice not a fix - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/900111

Can someone provide examples how to fix this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to have a UserSession table and insert a record into this table when the user logs in. When you logout either delete the entry or mark it invalid. On the secure pages, verify that a UserSession exists for the logged in user and redirect to a login page if it does not.

Comment: I think thats why I will try but use the Session object instead of a DB table. I can't believe that this is still an issue with ASP.Net, surely this is a massive security issue

Answer (score 0):

set a session value on login, clear it on log out and check it on each access to a secure page. The session value is not sent to the client and as such the client/attacker can not manipulate it.

walkthrough without session value cleared on exit :
user visits login page - generates viewstate
man-in-the-middle-hacker collects viewstate

user submits login form - generates auth cookies
man-in-the-middle-hacker collects auth cookies

user logs out - server clears users cookies
man-in-the-middle-hacker continues to use previous credentials completely unhindered
game over

walkthrough wit session value cleared on exit :
user visits login page - generates viewstate
man-in-the-middle-hacker collects viewstate

user submits login form - generates auth cookies
man-in-the-middle-hacker collects auth cookies

user logs out - server clears users cookies and sets its internal session flag value to null
man-in-the-middle-hacker continues to use previous credentials but because the session he is working with now has the value null server redirects to login page.
win!